# Xen on Ubuntu 18.04 with IPv4 (NAT) and IPv6

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, bridge, nat, xen

I'm renting a dedicated server at Hetzner and installed Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS on it.
I've got two public IPv4 addresses named x.x.x.x and y.y.y.y and one IPv6 /64 block for connecting my private networks to the internet. I use NAT for IPv4.

[image: XEN Schema]
My network is configured using Netplan as follows:

```
network:    
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
        - x.x.x.x/32
        - y.y.y.y/32
        - a.a.a.a::2/64
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: z.z.z.z
      gateway6: fe80::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 1.0.0.1
          - 2606:4700:4700::1111
          - 2606:4700:4700::1001
  bridges:
    xenbr0:
      interfaces: []
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.1/24
        - a.a.a.a::3/64
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: false
    xenbr1:
      interfaces: []
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1/24
        - a.a.a.a::4/64
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: false
```

The installation and configuration of XEN:

```
sudo apt-get install xen-hypervisor-amd64 xen-tools
sudo reboot
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
   GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN_DEFAULT="dom0_mem=min:1024M,max:1024M dom0_max_vcpus=2 dom0_vcpus_pin"
sudo vim /etc/xen/xl.conf
   autoballoon=0
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

VM's should be accessible to and from the Internet using IP forwarding and NAT.

```
sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf
   net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

The NAT part:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Forward HTTP and HTTPS requests to our VM2 server:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -i eth0 -d x.x.x.x --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.11:80
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -i eth0 -d x.x.x.x --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.11:443
```

We don't want any traffic between 192.168.0.x <-> 192.168.0.y so we drop all data packages with some simple rules. This Blocks communication between the bridges:

```
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o xenbr0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i xenbr0 -o eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o xenbr1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i xenbr1 -o eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

The IPv4 part works perfectly but the IPv6 doesn't. I've assigned an IPv6 address manually to my VM's.When logged in to VM1 i can ping xenbr0 at address ::3 and VM2 at address ::11 but can't ping eth0 at address ::2.
It's like the bridge prevents the IPv6 traffic from leaving the network but can't figure out why.

Comment: If you are trying to create a guide, the re-write to be a question, and answer it. (self answered questions are encouraged).

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure it out. The key is to use an ipv6 address with /128 netmask that will function as a gateway for your VM's.
Let's start with modifying the Netplan config:

```
network:    
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
        - x.x.x.x/32
        - y.y.y.y/32
        - a.a.a.a::00/128
        - a.a.a.a::10/128
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: z.z.z.z
      gateway6: fe80::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 1.0.0.1
          - 2606:4700:4700::1111
          - 2606:4700:4700::1001
  bridges:
    xenbr0:
      interfaces: []
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.1/24
        - a.a.a.a::00/125
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: false
    xenbr1:
      interfaces: []
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1/24
        - a.a.a.a::10/125
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: false
```

Pay attention to the ipv6 addresses assigned to the eth0, xenbr0 and xenbr1 interfaces. Eth0 gets two single ipv6 (/128) addresses while xenbr0 and xenbr1 gets a block of eight addresses (/125) that can be used for your VM's.
VM1 network config looks like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo0 inet6 loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    network 192.168.0.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address a:a:a:a::01
    netmask 125
    gateway a:a:a:a::00
```

And VM3 config which uses another bridge:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo0 inet6 loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address a:a:a:a::11
    netmask 125
    gateway a:a:a:a::10
```

Last but not least don't forget to enable ip forwarding for ipv6.

```
sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf
    net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```